# Which saddle is perfect for aggressive riding position?

Tags: saddle

Recently I have changed my position on my bike from upright to an aggressive one by lowering my stem. Now the major problem which I am facing these days is that I am very uncomfortable on the bike especially on the saddle part.

My current saddle is **PROLOGO NAGO EVO T2** especially for climbers as they do not move much on the saddle.

Now according to my research on the web about the saddles and which one is going to suit me and my aggressive riding position, I have concluded that **FIZIK ARIONE** saddle is the solution to my problem.

Now these are the following questions I have:-

Q1. Is fizik arione solution to my problem?

Q2. If it is, then which kind of padding I should choose

*R1          0mm

*VS          7mm

*VSX   20mm

Q3. If it is not, then which one should I  go for? Why?

Comment: Your discomfort may not be saddle driven.  Changes in position can cause unintended comfort consequences until your body has adapts to the new position.  How long have you been riding with the new position?

Comment: You have a decent general question, how do i select a saddle for a task or something, i suppose. but as its written right now, its more of a product rec question, so it might get closed.

Comment: I think your question is actually "Which saddle is perfect for aggressive riding position with my preferred stack height, hip and back flexibility, and pelvic-area morphology?" But I don't know anything about your flexibility, postural preferences, ischeal tuberosity spacing, or whatever. Neither does anyone else. Ideally you should try a few and see what you like.

Comment: To piggy back on @CalvinSmythe's point, you normally just dont slam the stem -- you go gradually so you get used to it on the way.

Comment: Saddles are too personal to give explicit advice.  The one that fits you is the one that fits you.   Now its a matter of finding that saddle without buying a bunch.  Some cities have saddle libraries where (for a fee) you can check-out, ride, and return saddles until you find the one that you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a perfect saddle according to your current position, you will spend a lot of money and never be happy with your purchase.  Marketers have created "specialized" (not the brand) seats so that we as consumers will buy more.  Think the number of variations you see in running shoe, or tooth paste.  They will all do the same thing with relatively equivalent effect.  The only thing different about them is the description and minor details.

Based on my experience, I have been able to change positions between casual and aggressive, depending on fitness, health and general season in life while keeping the same saddle.  How your bike fits dictates your riding comfort more than your saddle type.

Review what changing to aggressive position does.  First, you are lowering your handlebars, this alters the amount of weight you support with your arms and therefore changes how you hold yourself overall on your bike. The change also incrementally increases the distance between your saddle and handlebars - which in turns puts more stress on your saddle region.

To counteract this change, move your saddle forward. The best way to do this would be to measure from saddle front to the of your stem pre-adjustment. Slam your stem and move your seat forward until the distance between your stem and seat is equivalent.  This will help, but going into an aggressive position by definition trades some comfort for aerodynamics.

That being said, I don't want you to think I'm not for buying a new saddle.  Just have the right motivation.  Get one that fits your hip bone shape and has the right amount of padding that you desire personally - ignore the spec mumbo-jumbo.  I have an older model Fizik Arione and love it.  I highly recommend it regardless of your riding position.

Comment: Sir thank you very much for the motivation. I have tried what you are telling. I was used​ too the saddle in the upright position but when changed to aggressive that's when it all started. Sir just tell me how to choose saddle padding that's where I am confusex. The saddle will going to cost me €90 that too FDJ team edition.

Answer (score 4):

Saddles are highly personal -- theres no saddle that works for everyone (and even for one person, there generally isn't a best saddle for a wide range of settings). Also, terms like aggressive are highly subjective -- whats aggressive for you may be nothing to a racer.

If you have a saddle that is good for the type of riding you do, you can measure its width, length, etc. and find something similar.

If you don't have a saddle thats good for the type of riding you do, you can also use fit kits to get an idea of which saddle size is right for you (Specialized and others use proprietary ones to measure your sit bones and what not; basically sit on a fancy piece of cardboard and it will measure it out for you).

But, at the end of the day, you really need to try the saddle for a while in the setting that you're going to use it. Better shops should give you some leeway in returning a saddle that doesn't fit (maybe some fee or rental program), so you can try a few to find something that works for the type of riding you do.

Also, note that its not just the saddle, but how you position it -- the offset and angle and height. When you change something like the stem, you'll need to change these too. A better seatpost will have more options for adjusting this.

Also, as @Useless notes in the comments to the question itself, theres a bigger problem: Is the riding position you're attempting feasible given the bike you have and your body, independent of a saddle? It could be that you won't be having fun on that bike with the stem in that position regardless of the saddle setup.

Comment: you are right. My problem is not that I need to get used to it as saddle description itself says that it is semi round and for the riders who tents to right in a upright position. Saddle positioning won't help. I just asked that which fizik saddle I should choose

Comment: Saddle positioning may help -- it is something you normally have to change when lowering the stem. A lot of saddles have descriptions on them, but at the end of the day, a lot of it is marketting and you need to try to see if it works for you. Have you checked with local bike shops that might carry that saddle or something?

Comment: No I am Indian and not everywhere a good bike shop is available

Comment: Hey yo I am using 145mm slammed  stem on my 54 size frame now this is why I used the term the aggressive position. You tell me isn't that right.

Comment: Maybe. Depends on the bike, and depends on the rider. In any case, as I said in the comments above, changing things gradually is the way to go, not just slam it.